# Auto expand divs

Tags: html

Im not a web dev but I catch quickly. Excuse my grammer as I dont know the correct terms for web developing.

I have a div(id=mainContainer) that has inside innerContainer which floats to the right. The mainContainer expands when comments are added but I also would like the innContainer to expands aswel. Is this possible? And how?

Comment: I'm sure it's possible. It might be as simple as changing the target for some of your code. Could you post the code in its current state so we can have more to go on?

Answer (score 0):

Yes add the following under the innerContainer:

```
<div style="clear:both;height:1"></div>
```

Another solution could be to make the outer div float aswell.

Comment: Im doing the samething like this: http://tutorialzine.com/2010/03/sponsor-wall-flip-jquery-css/ If you look on the right,(darker gray col), I can bet that auto expands when comments are placed.

Answer (score 0):

Try floatting the innerContainer to the left.

```
<div id="mainContainer" >
    <div style="float:left">
    some content
    </div>
    <div class="innerContaier" style="float:left">
     some large content<br/>
     some large content<br/>
     some large content<br/>
     some large content<br/>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```